# When trying to add objects to a list i get the error "object not callable" in some cases but not in others.

Tags: python

I'm new to python and relatively new to programming in general and I'm trying to write a side scrolling arcade game using the pygame and random modules. However I have hit a stumbling block in the way that the game is populated with enemies. What I am trying to achieve to make it so that for every enemy that leaves the left hand side of the window a new one is spawned somewhere beyond the right hand edge of the window.

However when an enemy leaves the left hand side of the screen and my respawn function is called I get an "typeerror" that the plane object it is trying to add to the enemies list is not callable - I cannot figure out why this is.

To begin with. I have defined a class for each type of enemy in my game. I have tried to get the planes to respawn the way i want them to first and then plan to do the same for the others. so I will only include relevant code to this class of enemies.

```
class plane(object):
    def __init__(self, start_x, start_y, speed):
        self.start_x = start_x
        self.start_y = start_y
        self.speed = speed
        self.width = 200
        self.height = 60
        self.Hitbox = (self.start_x, self.start_y, self.width, 
self.height)


    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,0), (self.start_x, self.start_y, 
self.width, self.height),0)
        self.Hitbox = (self.start_x, self.start_y, self.width, 
self.height)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,255,0), self.Hitbox, 1)
```

I can create an initial list of enemies by using the following create level function before entering the main loop of the game and i have defined another function called Respawn() It's this Respawn() function that won't work in the way i hoped:

```
turrets = []
towers = []
planes = []

def createLevel():
    for r in range(left_turret_number):
        turrets.append(turret(random.randint(1,2651), "Diag_left"))

    for r in range(right_turret_number):
        turrets.append(turret(random.randint(1,2651), "up"))

    for r in range(tower_number):
        towers.append(tower(random.randint(150,2651),random.randint(1,450), 
50))

    for r in range(plane_number):
        planes.append(plane(random.randint(500,2651), random.randint(1, 
450), random.randint(10, 20)))



def Respawn():

    random_plane_x = random.randint(500,2651)
    random_plane_y = random.randint(1, 450)
    random_plane_speed = random.randint(10, 20)
    random_plane = plane(random_plane_x, random_plane_y, 
    random_plane_speed)


    print(random_plane_x, random_plane_y, random_plane_speed)
    planes.append(random_plane)
```

In my main loop the pertinent following things happen in this order:

1.) each plane is moved by their speed towards the left of the window

```
    for plane in planes:
            plane.start_x -= plane.speed
```

2.) each plane is checked to see whether it has completely left the left hand side of the window, and if it has, it is removed from the list and the respawn counter increases by one - I have done it this way in case two planes by chance leave the screen at the same time.

```
    for plane in planes:
            plane.start_x -= plane.speed
```

3.) for the number of respawn counters, the respawn function is called that many times. (this is after collisons have been detected and keyboard input checked for ect.). finally the respawn counter is reset and the game window redrawn.

```
    if plane_respawn_counter > 0:
            for r in range(plane_respawn_counter):
                Respawn()


        plane_respawn_counter = 0
        redrawGameWindow()
```

When a plane leaves the left hand side of the screen and the respawn function is triggered the program simply crashes and I get the error message "TypeError:  "plane" object is not callable".

Thank you for your attention - I hope someone can tell me why the object is not callable and hopefully also how I can fix it :) I hope the information I have provided is sufficient - please let me know if you need any more details or need to see any further code from my program.

Answer (score 2):

You should rename your variable in your for loop from `planes`--`planes` is the name of your class. Here is where I'm talking about:

```
for plane in planes:
        plane.start_x -= plane.speed
```

In your respawn function, you call `plane`,

```
random_plane = plane(random_plane_x, random_plane_y, random_plane_speed)
```

but planes has been redefined as an instance of your class `plane`, therefore your error `object not callable`. Try just changing your for-loop variable to something else or renaming your class to `Plane` (it's pretty standard for them to start with an uppercase letter).